# Python: Log the name and output of each method in a Class automatically

Tags: python, logging

I have a module, that is a wrapper class for C programs.

Each method has various inputs, but the outputs are typically the same, a file name.

```
class Wrapper(object): 
    def wrapper1(self, infile, outfile):
        do_stuff

        log.info('wrapper1:%s' %outfile)
```

I've already written 50 methods before I realized that I want this behaviour.

Plus, there's got to be an elegant way of adding a logger w/o adding that line to all methods.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [decorator](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808):

```
import functools
def log(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, infile, outfile):
        retval = func(self, infile, outfile)
        log.info('wrapper1:%s' %outfile)
        return retval
    return wrapper

class Wrapper(object):
    @log
    def wrapper1(self, infile, outfile):
        do_stuff
```

Comment: Don't forget to forward infile/outfile to `func`

Comment: I'll have to study that answer, thanks ! And there should be a way to get the name of the method automagically as well correct ?

Comment: ok...I think it got to work...don't understand all the bit just yet...wrapper.__name__ will get me the method name I'm looking for.Let me implement it and then I'll accept...Thanks again.